# Server Side Pagination Using Angular 7 And NgxPagination

Tags: angular, ngx-pagination

I'm trying to code pagination using **NgxPagination**. But I don't know how to pass **pageIndex** from component to service. It only display one page only. And can't go to next page.[image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtB48.jpg)

I provided code bellow for your reference.

**HTML**

```
<ng-container
  matColumnDef="{{ column }}"
  *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay | paginate: { id: 'server',
  itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: total }"
          >... </ng-container>    
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="loadData($event)" id="server"></pagination-controls>
```

**Component ts**

```
length:number;
  pageIndex :number;
  p: number = 1;
  total: number;

  loadData(pageIndex){

  this.listservice.getListService(pageIndex).subscribe(res =>{
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ListDetails>(res);

  this.total = res.total;
  this.p = pageIndex;

}
```

And in my service code I make like bellow

**service**

```
getListService(page:number): Observable<any>  {
    const urls: string = `http://192.168.0.101:9080/projek/api/listall/${Id}`
   const rUrl: string = `${urls}/${page + 1}/desc`;
    return this.http.get<AllDetails>(rUrl).pipe(map(res => res['allList']));
  }
```

What should I add to make it work.

Hope you all can help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change

```
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="loadData($event)" id="server"></pagination-controls>
```

to

```
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="loadAgents($event)" id="server"></pagination-controls>
```

As there is no `loadData` method in your component

Answer (score 0):

In any case did you forgot to add the paginate pipe on the mattable's datasource? Something like

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="listData | paginate { ... }">
  ...
</table>
```

Comment: I've put it  `*ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay | paginate: { id: 'server', itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: total }"` but it does not work too

Comment: How many is the count of your api result? Maybe it does not create other pages because it is less than your itemsPerPage?

Comment: Actually, My APi like this.. `http://192.168.0.101:9080/project/api/listall/com/1/desc`. Number 1 refer to page. If change to 2 it go to page 2 and so on... That why I put `${page + 1}` in my service to plus page. But I don't know why it does not work

Comment: In your api are you returning the total rows of your data in your db?

this.total = res.total;

Comment: backend code being set to 10 rows perpage to display

Comment: I see, I think you should use the overall total of your data in your total in the component.

It is like your total is 10 divided by 10 per page so it is 1 it should be something like total is 100 divided by 10 per page so you'll get 10 pages

Comment: oo.. I see... So, I need backend to pass all data..And let forntend to control it... Thank you so much... I understood..

Comment: even not all data. Just the total of all data